# Clojure concat 2d elements to the same String

Tags: clojure

I have data in the following format:

```
[[123][124][125][126][127]]
```

And I ultimately want to produce a String which will look like

```
123,
124,
125,
126,
127
```

So I need to iterate the vector, apply ",\n" to the elements and then remove the ",\n" from the last one (or dont even add it in the first place)

I have tried the following (data is the `[[123][124][125][126][127]]` vector):

```
(mapv (fn [inner] (mapv #(str  % ",\n") inner)) data)
```

Which produces:

```
[[123,
] [124,
] [125,
] [126,
] [127,
]]
```

I dont really want to do a replace statement to remove `[]` from the String, but then again I'm stumped on how to convert the data to a better format before mapping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user>(def data [[123][124][125][126][127]])
;; => #'user/data
user> (clojure.string/join ",\n" (flatten data))
;; => "123,
124,
125,
126,
127"
```

Comment: Should this not be still passed to `println` like: `user=> (println (clojure.string/join ", \n" (flatten data)))  123,  124,  125,  126,  127  nil`  ? Otherwise it returns `"123,\n124,\n125,\n126,\n127"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(clojure.string/join ",\n" (mapv #(clojure.string/join ",\n" %) data))
```

Comment: Works thank you! Can I ask, how does that not append the `,\n"` to the last element in the vector? does it not join `,\n"` to every element in data?

Comment: join (in clojure as in many other languages) does just that. Joins lists by putting a separator between every two elements. btw, @slipset's answer is better, you should go with that.